# Why must $K/\Bbb Q$ be Galois for $[KF(z):KF]$ to divide $[K(z):K]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I was reading through [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27643106?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3A8f739bf6eb956d13822731889fc3aaf3&seq=4#page_scan_tab_contents) article discussing irrationality / rationality of trigonometric functions and at which values. I’ve been following it and enjoying reading it, but I’m stumped by one of the final remarks regarding degrees of compositum fields.

On page 198 of the magazine we have the following setup:

> $F$ is a subfield of the constructible numbers, obtain as part of a chain of quadratic extensions, and is Galois. $K$ is some Galois extension of the rationals. The adjoined element $z=\cos\theta$ is algebraic over (and not contained in) both fields $K,F$.

The author claims: $[KF(z):KF]$ divides $[K(z):K]$ *since $K/\Bbb Q$ is Galois.*

This isn’t clear to me. The minimal polynomial for $z$ over $K$, $m_2$ is again a polynomial with $z$ as a root over $KF$, so the minimal polynomial over $KF$, $m_1$, divides that over $K$. To say the degree divides, I think, is likely going to involve arguing that some power of $m_1$ is $m_2$. But I don’t see how one can argue this in general as the coefficients of $m_1$ are hard to relate to those of $m_2$, potentially involving elements of a different field.

I would really appreciate hints on how to prove $[KF(z):KF]$ divides $[K(z):K]$, and why $K$ must be Galois over $\Bbb Q$. After all the problem statement doesn’t really involve $\Bbb Q$, so it seems a bit of a red herring. We know $F=\Bbb Q(\gamma)$ for some primitive element $\gamma$, so really it suffices to think about $[K(\gamma,z):K(\gamma)]$ versus $[K(z):K]$.

Comment: If $z$ is independent of $K$, shouldn't the extension $K(z)/K$ be infinite?

Comment: @KentaS Sorry, I meant a different thing and forgot “independent” implied algebraically independent in this context

Comment: We need $K(z)/K$ Galois. Try with $K=\Bbb{Q}, z=2^{1/3}, F=\Bbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi /3} 2^{1/3})$

Comment: @reuns Oh. How do you arrive at the need for $K(z)/K$ Galois anyway? I don’t understand these divisibility criteria, the Galois theory course I took never covered compositums in any detail (reading again through the paper, as it happens $K(z)/K$ is Galois too)

Comment: $KF(z)/KF$ will be Galois as well and its Galois group will be a subgroup of $Gal(K(z)/K)$, whence the divisibility.

Comment: @reuns Hm. It cannot literally be a subgroup since $KF(z)/KF$ generally won’t be a subextension of $K(z)/K$. So, there must be some identification mapping at play - I do not know what that would be.

Comment: @reuns I think I’ve figured it out now. $KF(z)/KF$ inherits normality and is then Galois, and any automorphism of $K(\gamma,z)/K(\gamma)$ easily restricts to one of $K(z)$. Thank you very much for your help and for pointing out that I needed to focus on a different thing… I might have wasted a lot of time on this otherwise